# Dag is stuck running

Tags: airflow

I just installed airflow 2.7.3 with default config (SQLite as metadata DB/SequentialExecutor) and tried running a Dag. The first simple task that creates a table in Postgres executes successfully. The next task HttpSensor gets stuck in "running" state. This dag runs successfully in other instances (inside docker containers). When I run this Dag on this new install, I get errors and warnings below (image- [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NHFV.png):

```
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.582-0600] {scheduler_job_runner.py:722} INFO - TaskInstance Finished: dag_id=user_processing, task_id=create_table, run_id=scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00, map_index=-1, 
run_start_date=2024-02-18 03:15:10.523261+00:00, run_end_date=2024-02-18 03:15:11.128272+00:00, run_duration=0.605011, state=success, executor_state=success, try_number=1, max_tries=0, job_id=49, pool=default_pool, queue=default, priority_weight=5, operator=PostgresOperator, queued_dttm=2024-02-18 03:15:06.785081+00:00, queued_by_job_id=48, pid=26667
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.660-0600] {scheduler_job_runner.py:413} INFO - 1 tasks up for execution:
        <TaskInstance: user_processing.is_api_available scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00 [scheduled]>
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.660-0600] {scheduler_job_runner.py:476} INFO - DAG user_processing has 0/16 running and queued tasks
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.660-0600] {scheduler_job_runner.py:592} INFO - Setting the following tasks to queued state:
        <TaskInstance: user_processing.is_api_available scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00 [scheduled]>
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.661-0600] {taskinstance.py:1441} WARNING - cannot record scheduled_duration for task is_api_available because previous state change time has not been saved
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.661-0600] {scheduler_job_runner.py:635} INFO - Sending TaskInstanceKey(dag_id='user_processing', task_id='is_api_available', run_id='scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00', try_number=1, map_index=-1) to executor with priority 4 and queue default
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.662-0600] {base_executor.py:146} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'user_processing', 'is_api_available', 'scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/user_processing.py']
[2024-02-17T21:15:11.665-0600] {sequential_executor.py:74} INFO - Executing command: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'user_processing', 'is_api_available', 'scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/user_processing.py']
[2024-02-17T21:15:12.746-0600] {dagbag.py:536} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/jacobdol/Documents/airflow/dags/user_processing.py
[2024-02-17T21:15:14.274-0600] {task_command.py:416} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: user_processing.is_api_available scheduled__2024-02-17T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]> on host jacobs-air.lan
```

Thanks!

Comment: The HttpSensor operator by default runs repeatedly with an interval of 60 seconds unless the response check returns or if it gets a 404. You can check the response by using a callable to 'break'out of this loop.

Comment: I checked this task by using tasks test and it runs successfully. This only happens when I try to execute the whole Dag. I also get this message occasionally in the Airflow UI - "The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 8 minutes ago." I wonder if it's some sort of the memory issue since the first simple task that creates a table in the db executes successfully.

Comment: Would you be able to share a snippet of the HttpSensor task and the response_check callable function.

Comment: Sure. @subram -  `check_api = HttpSensor(task_id ="is_api_available",
                           http_conn_id="user_api",
                           timeout=300, 
                           endpoint='/api') ` I don't call any functions, as I understand, if the HTTPSensor executes successfully, the next task will start.